# Undefined Variable In document.write

Tags: javascript, json

I keep getting "toggleOnlyRelatedPosts is not defined " in Chrome console and the script doesn't work. I'm working on this script and I've gotten lost after adding so many variables. I'm not that good at this sort of thing and to me it looks clearly defined, but I guess it's not. Chrome marks the error at the document.write

Here is the script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
    function postGrabber(json) {

            // The Magic
            for (var i = 0; i < json.feed.entry.length; i++) {
                for (var j = 0; j < json.feed.entry[i].link.length; j++) {
                    if (json.feed.entry[i].link[j].rel == 'alternate') {
                        var postUrl = json.feed.entry[i].link[j].href;
                        break;
                    }
                }

            // Thumbnail Stuff
            var orgImgUrl = json.feed.entry[i].media$thumbnail.url ? json.feed.entry[i].media$thumbnail.url : 'http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-mxinHrJWpBo/VD6fqbvI74I/AAAAAAAAcn8/LslulDeOROg/s72-c/noimage-chalkboard.jpg';
            var newImgUrl = orgImgUrl.replace('s72-c', 's' + imgSize + '-c');
            var imgTag = '<a class="item-link-post" href="' + postUrl + '"><img class="item-img-thumbnail" src="' + newImgUrl + '" width="' + imgSize + '" height="' + imgSize + '"/></a>';

            var authorName = json.feed.entry[i].author[0].name.$t;
            var authorURL = json.feed.entry[i].author[0].uri.$t;
            var authorOriImgUrl = json.feed.entry[i].author[0].gd$image.src;
            var authorNewImgUrl = authorOriImgUrl.replace('s512-c', 's' + authorImgSize + '-c');
            var authorImgTag = '<a class="item-link-author" href="' + authorURL + '" target="_blank" rel="nofollow"><img class="item-img-author" src="' + authorNewImgUrl + '" alt="' + authorName + '"/></a>';

            var postLabel = json.feed.category[i].term;
            var postLabelUrl = '/-/' + postLabel + '';

            // Standard Stuff
            var postTitle = json.feed.entry[i].title.$t;
            var postCommentCount = json.feed.entry[i].thr$total.$t;

            var postSummary = json.feed.entry[i].summary.$t;
            var entryShort = postSummary.substring(0, '' + summaryLength + '');
            var entryEnd = entryShort.lastIndexOf(" ");
            var postContent = entryShort.substring(0, entryEnd) + '...';

            var postDate = json.feed.entry[i].updated.$t ? json.feed.entry[i].updated.$t : json.feed.entry[i].published.$t;
            var shortDate = postDate.substring(0,10);

            // Let's Make Options Here
            var toggleImg = showImg ? '' + imgTag + '' : '';
            var toggleTitle = showTitle ? '<h1 class="item-title">' + postTitle + '</h1>' : '';
            var toggleSummary = showSummary ? '<p class="item-snippet">' + postContent + '</p>' : '';
            var toggleDate = showDate ? '<span class="item-date">' + shortDate + '</span>' : '';
            var toggleAuthorImg = showAuthorImg ? '' + authorImgTag + '' : '';
            var toggleCommentCount = showCommentCount ? '<span class="item-comment-count">' + postCommentCount + '</span>' : '';


            var toggleOnlyRelatedPosts = showOnlyRelatedPosts ? '' + postLabelUrl + '' : '';

            // The Output
            var itemPost = '<div class="item-post"><div class="item-imgs">' + toggleImg + toggleAuthorImg + '</div>' + toggleCommentCount + '<a class="item-link" href=' + postUrl + '>' + toggleTitle + '</a>' + toggleSummary + toggleDate + '</div>';

            // Let's Write It Down
            document.write(itemPost);
        }
    }
    //]]>
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
    var imgSize = 96;
    var summaryLength = 142;
    var authorImgSize = 36;
    var showImg = true; 
    var showTitle = true; 
    var showSummary = true; 
    var showDate = true;
    var showAuthorImg = true;
    var showCommentCount = true;
    var showOnlyRelatedPosts = true;
    document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="/feeds/posts/summary' + toggleOnlyRelatedPosts + '?orderby=published&amp;max-results=5&amp;alt=json-in-script&amp;callback=postGrabber"><\/script>');
    //]]>
</script>
```

Comment: FYI, you can write `var a=1,b=2, ... z=n` rather than `var a=1, var b=2,... var z=n`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable `toggleOnlyRelatedPosts` is declared in the scope of the function `postGrabber`. It is therefore indeed undefined in the line with the `document.write`, where you try to use it.

If you wish to use those variables outside the function you have to declare them outside the function.

[Read up on the concept of 'scope'](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var), it's pretty fundamental knowledge in any programming language.